# Lync Plugin with Localhost

Tags: plugins, xampp, localhost, lync

Is there any way I can have this Microsoft Lync plugin (as described here):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2013/03/02/integrate-lync-into-your-intranet-sites-using-the-namectrl-plug-in.aspx

work on a localhost? (i'm using xampp)

I'm not an experienced developer as you can probably guess, but I'm currently trying to develop an internal directory site for work.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else ever gets stuck on this, I figured it out.

It required using IE, and putting localhost into the list of trusted sites.

Comment: This will also fix it for other browsers.